# jQuery not detecting anything from my selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am making an extension. I have the following code in my `content.js`:

```js
var elems2 = $("div[id^='ad-'],div[id*=' ad-']");

console.log(elems2.length);

$(window).on('load', function() {
    for (var i = 0, max = elems2.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems2.hidden = true;
    };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0, max = elems2.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems2.hidden = true;
    };
});

for (var i = 0, max = elems2.length; i < max; i++) {
    elems2.hidden = true;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="adContent-border" style="border-color: rgb(229, 229, 229); border-radius: 0px; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 500; box-sizing: border-box; pointer-events: none;"></div>
```

My `manifest.json`:

```json
{
"manifest_version":2,
"name":"Test",
"description":"A Basic program",
"version":"0.1",
"background":{
   "scripts":[

   ]
},
"content_scripts":[
   {
      "matches":[
         "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js":[
         "jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
         "content.js"
      ]
   }
],

"browser_action":{
   "default_title":"Test"
  }
}
```

But when this runs, it does not do anything. I found the problem when I put the code `alert(elems2.length)` and it returned 0, Therefore JQuery didn't detect it. Does anyone know how to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: id stating with a space?

Comment: Move `var elems2 = $("div[id^='ad-'],div[id*=' ad-']");` inside document-ready handler and Identifiers can't contains space. And what are you trying to achieve using `elems2.hidden`?

Comment: @Satpal making it invisible/hiding in the page i guess...

Comment: @Jai, Does jQuery object has `hidden` property?

Comment: please include a [mcve] in your question.  We cannot troubleshoot with only the JS, we also need the HTML so we can see why some selectors are not working.

Comment: @ochi oh ok. I am making an extension so I don't have a HTML page

Comment: then the markup you are trying to select from?

Comment: @ochi I am trying to select all the `div` tags with 'ad' in their `id`

Comment: did you already try `var elem2 = $("div[id~='ad']");` ? (https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_attribute_value_contains.asp)

Comment: @ochi yes and I also did `alert(elem2.length)` and it returned 0

Comment: Your content script does not depend on any Chrome extension APIs. I have moved it into a [snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so that its operation is a bit easier to see. I also added a `console.log(elems2.length);` to show how many elements were selected.

Comment: Is the HTML you added really the element you are attempting to match? The ID in the HTML does not contain `ad-`, which is what you appear to be attempting to match. If that is the element you are trying to match, then changing your selector to only be looking for `ad` does match it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the attribute 'contains' selector (https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) you don't need to add the 'starts with' selector.

I.e. use: `$("div[id*='ad']")`

Also, I am not sure how you are loading your jquery but make sure you include your definition of the var inside the 'load' event.

I.e.

```
$(window).load(function() {
    var elem2 = $("div[id*='ad']");
    ...
 });
```

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  var elem2 = $("div[id*='ad']");

  $.each(elem2, function(idx, elem) {
    console.log(idx + "-" + $(elem).text());
    $(elem).addClass('with-ad');
  });
});
```

```css
.with-ad {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="my-answer">
  <div id="advert">Starts with 'ad'</div>
  <div id="edvert">Does not starts with 'ad'</div>
  <div id="madonna">Contains 'ad'</div>
  <div id="maronna">Does not contain 'ad'</div>
  <div id="rad">ends in 'ad'</div>
  <div id="raz">does not end in 'ad'</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the elems2 var when the document isn't ready, that can cause that you script execute the initialization before the elements you're trying to detect doesn't exist already.

try this

```
var elems2 = null;
$(window).on('load', function() {
    for (var i = 0, max = elems2.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems2.hidden = true;
    };
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    elems2 = $("div[id^='ad-'],div[id*=' ad-']");
    for (var i = 0, max = elems2.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems2.hidden = true;
    };
});

for (var i = 0, max = elems2.length; i < max; i++) {
    elems2.hidden = true;
};
```