# How to select an element on a page with the mouse and hide it in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mouse

I am making a test extension for chrome.
My Question:

Is it possible to make an event script to  select an element with the mouse and hide it? something like the inspect element selection tool when you press `Shift+Ctrl+C`. Note: I don't want a DOM reflow after.

Here is my code:

content.js:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");

$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0, max = elems.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems[i].hidden = true;
    };
});

window.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 0, max = elems.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems[i].hidden = true;
    }
};

$(window).load(function() {
    for (var i = 0, max = elems.length; i < max; i++) {
        elems[i].hidden = true;
    };
});

for (var i = 0, max = elems.length; i < max; i++) {
    elems[i].hidden = true;
};
```

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "name":"Test",
  "description":"A Basic program",
  "version":"0.1",
  "background":{
     "scripts":[

     ]
  },
  "content_scripts":[
     {
        "matches":[
           "<all_urls>"
        ],
        "js":[
          "jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
          "content.js"
        ]
     }
  ],

  "browser_action":{
     "default_title":"Test"
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for adding code, that, hopefully, will help define your question. However, what you are wanting to do is still not clear. Are you wanting the selection to be hidden when a keyboard shortcut is pressed? From a context menu entry? How?  Even with the code, which appears to be the same you posted in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43488135/3773011), This reads like a request for us to write code, which A) isn't really what Stack Overflow is for, and B) your request is still to vague for us to be able to actually write something.

Comment: If you are wanting us to debug the code you already have, then: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask]. Even if the code included is a [mcve], you would still need to tell us #1 (the text doesn't currently match the code), and #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a load of different ways to select an element, and a load more to hide it.

First you can add context menu items with [`chrome.contextMenus.create`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create).

To handle key chords (like `SHFT+CTRL+C`) you'll need a background script in the page.

In this event you can manipulate the DOM to hide the the element. Use `element.style.display = 'none'` to collapse content around it, or `element.style.opacity = '0'` to hide it while keeping the rest of the page unchanged.

Looking at your source code:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe");
```

OK, this should get all the `<iframe>` tags in the page, assuming that they have loaded in. By default [content scripts fire after the DOM is complete but can be before or after the onload event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts).

Next up...

```
$(document).ready(function() { ...
window.onload = function() { ...
$(window).load(function() { ...
```

These appear to be different attempts to hook this up to the document having finished loading. The problem is that `window.onload` may (or may not) have already fired. You can force the content script to run before `window.onload` with `"run_at": "document_end"` in the `manifest.json`, but I don't think that's what you want.

Note that all of them are using the `elems` variable that you got from the DOM with an inline script, so if the `<iframe>` wasn't there before the events fire then it won't be in the array.

Finally all of these appear to be trying to loop the `<iframe>`s:

```
for (var i = 0, max = elems.length; i < max; i++) {
    elems[i].hidden = true;
};
```

This is fine, though use `elems[i].style.visibility = 'hidden'` to avoid reflowing the DOM. So (using ES6 syntax which Chrome extensions support):

```
function hideIframes() {
    const elems = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe');
    for (let e of elems) {
        e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    };
}

// Don't do all of these - pick one that suits your context
hideIframes(); // Run inline on document_idle
$(hideIframes); // Run on jQuery complete
setTimeout(hideIframes, 3000); // Run again in 3s
```

I think your problem is that the `<iframe>`s that you're looking for are not yet in the page when the content script runs. You may need to add a check against the specific event you think is adding them.

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you please provide me with a basic example?

Comment: @Vagif yeah, but the question is too vague. Is this going to be a context menu action or an event script? Do you want to disable normal actions while making selections, do you want to hide or remove the element? Do you want a DOM reflow afterwards?

Comment: edited my answer now

Comment: @Vagif to avoid DOM reflow use `element.style.opacity = '0'` to make the element completely see through or `element.style.visibility = 'hidden'`

Comment: may you please provide an example?

Comment: @Vagif You could also try `document.getElementById('element_ID').style.visibility = 'hidden'` I can't really be more specific without seeing the code you've got so far.

Comment: updated my answer

Comment: @Vagif expanded